# how to swap models between views in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If I have two view A and B. A has model X and B has model Y. A click event in B will trigger the model in view A to change to the model in view B, what is the best way to do this?

I was thinking of triggering an event that A would listen from B that would then pass the new model to A from B, but I see this as a wrong way to do it.

The other method would be passing the model of A to B so B would have a reference to it and be able to change it, but I think this defeats the whole purpose of MVC.

Here's a bit of the code in view B of the click event:

```
// display item picture or item Detail View
    viewItem : function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        //change the parent model to this one

    },
```

Comment: How does passing the model to a view defeats MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You are definately on the right track using events.

However, separation of concearns means that view A should not have any knowledge or references to B.

Rather, view A should just push an event with Model X as part of the message to a message bus of some sort.  View B should be listening to this message bus, and react when it receives an event.

This means that anyone can listen to this event - and you can easily swap View B out with View C in the future if needed.